# How to create a Legend with Core Plot in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot, legend

I have created a CPTXYGraph using Core Plot in Swift. The graph works just fine. Now I am trying to add a legend. I have looked at several examples and come up with the following to create the legend:

```
    var theLegend=CPTLegend(graph: graph)
    var legendFill=CPTFill(color: CPTColor.blueColor())
    theLegend.fill = legendFill
    var legendLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    legendLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.whiteColor()
    theLegend.borderLineStyle = legendLineStyle
    theLegend.cornerRadius = 2.0
    theLegend.swatchSize = CGSizeMake(15.0, 15.0)
    graph.legend = theLegend
    graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchor.TopLeft
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(100.0, -100.0)
```

When I run this, I get a blue square with slightly rounded corners that appears to be about 10 X 10 pixels. 
I tried setting the frame just to see if it would make a difference:

```
    theLegend.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
```

This did not change anything.

Has anyone had any success with this in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your plots are already in the graph before using that legend initializer. You can also initialize a legend with an array of individual plots.

Comment: Eric, yes, all plots are already in the graph. I did also try to initialize the legend with an array of plots but it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here : [Problems with legend in Core-Plot (pieChart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253533/problems-with-legend-in-core-plot-piechart)

You need to add this method

```
func legendTitleForPieChart(pieChart:CPTPieChart,recordIndex index:Int) -> NSString{
    return "the title"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 things:

this delegate:

```
CPTPieChartDelegate
```

You need set the delegate to self on piechart:

```
pieChart.delegate = self
```

and feed the legend:

```
func legendTitleForPieChart(pieChart: CPTPieChart!, recordIndex idx: UInt) -> String! {
    return "titulo"
}
```

Comment: I have all of that set, but still the method is not getting called. Could I be missing anything else?